# Can I publish my novel as a 13 year old?

Tags: creative-writing, young-author

I’m writing a short novel about a young teenage girl who loses her brother and comes close to death. She travel around trying to find his killer and comes face to face with great challenges along the way. I just started this book and I am wondering if it is possible for me to get it published. The only problem is that I’m only 13 and my family doesn’t think I’m all that serious about writing. But I really am, as I have set my heart on being an author and inspire other young people like me. It would really help if anyone has any information on how I can reach my life goal, as it would mean the world to me.

Comment: You might want to tell us where you are from, because the rights of minors to engage in commerce are very different in different countries.

Comment: Echoing the answers and comments on that per-existing question: You can totally publish a book at any age, but you don't have bills to pay, so focus for now on writing the best book you can! (it sounds like you're off to a good start)

Comment: Hi Maya, this is a good question, but one that has been asked MANY times before on our site.  One such question is linked above, but here are others that may have useful answers: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/19194/i-am-a-16-year-old-who-wants-to-be-a-writer-but-can-i https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/39457/publishing-my-book https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/33234/how-to-get-my-book-taken-seriously-as-a-teenager